# what will happen when one peer is using `send()` or `recv()` if the other peer closes its tcp connection

Tags: tcp, network-programming

if there is a tcp connection between process A and B 
if B closes its tcp connection by

```
      shutdown(tcpfd, SHUT_RDWR);

      or

     shutdown(tcpfd, SHUT_RD);

      or 

     shutdown(tcpfd, SHUT_WR);
```

how can A know that B did one of the 3 actions above?

and if A does:

```
      send(tcpfd, buf, len, 0);
```

what will happen?

BTW, if B doesnt send FIN/ACK, it just sends a RST
and A is waiting for receiving packets

```
    while(1){
      n=recv(tcpfd, buf, len, 0);
     }
```

how can A know that B sends a RST?  n will be 0?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When A tries to `send`, if B has closed the read end of the connection `send` will signal this error by returning -1. A can then decide what to do about the situation.

Correspondingly when A tries to `read` and assuming no data has been buffered locally, if B has closed the write end of the connection `read` will simply return 0.

Comment: are you sure about the second sentence, it seems to me that `read` or `recv` will return 0 if B closed the write end of the connection

Comment: The 2nd part is wrong. `read()` will return 0, indicating an EOF condition.

Comment: @user1944267: You are right, I edited to correct. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: how about the case of RST and when `send` returns `-1`, what `errno` corresponds to the cases

Comment: @Jon : +1. Simple Explanation.